# best way to test for JSON null value in JSON being returned with AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7, afnetworking-2

I have a JSON payload being returned that could either be null or value. Like:

```
post: {
   header:"here is my header",
   current_instore_anncouncement: null
}
```

or when there is a `current_instore_announcement`:

```
post: {
   header:"here is my header",
   current_instore_anncouncement: {header: "announcement header"}
}
```

I am using `AFNetworking 2.0` and want to either show the `current_isntore_announcement` if it exists or do nothing if it returns null.

How would I properly check for the existence of the `current_instore_anncouncement`? I have:

```
NSDictionary *current_instore_announcement=[result objectForKey:@"current_instore_anncouncement"];

if(current_instore_announcement){
  InstoreAnnoucement *splashAnnouncement = [[InstoreAnnoucement alloc] initWithAttributes:current_instore_announcement];
if(splashAnnouncement){
    NSLog(@"theres an instore announcement");
}else{
    NSLog(@"nadda = instore announcement with %@",current_instore_announcement);
}
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
[NSNull notNullObjectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

### Edit #1

It looks like the best way is to check for it not being NSNull. Like so:

```
if(![current_instore_announcement isEqual:[NSNull class]]){
```

or to create an addition to NSDictionary like this:

```
#import "NSDictionary+Additions.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (Additions)

- (id)notNullObjectForKey:(id)aKey {
    id obj = [self objectForKey:aKey];
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    return obj;
}
```

Any other / better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use following methods:

```
if(![current_instore_announcement isEqual:[NSNull class]]){
    // Not null
}
else{
    // null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The good way to check this is by following method. please check this:

```
- (BOOL) hasValue:(id)object {

    if(object!=nil && (NSNull *)object != [NSNull null])    {

    // Check NSString Class
    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] || [object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableString class]]) {
        if([object length]>0) {
            return YES;
        }
     } 

    // Check UIImage Class
    if([object isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]){
        if ([object CGImage]!=nil) {
            return YES;
        }
     }

    // Check NSArray Class
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] || [object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
        if ([object count] > 0) {
            return YES;
        }
     }
    else {
        return YES;
     }
  }
  return NO;
 }
```

and than you have to check every time for every object from your json response.

Comment: Do NOT use `(NSNull *)object != [NSNull null]`. It just compares the offset of vars. In order to compare objects, use `isEqual:` method

Comment: @NtVietHung: your way is not very good for testing NULL value in json reponse. "isEqual:" method i don't prefer in testing NULL value in json response. anyway thanks for comment.

Comment: You should learn more about cursor! Comparing 2 cursors is not useful in this case!

Comment: Please be nice on stack overflow. You Can't campare 2 cursors. Only you have to check the values in cursor.

Comment: NtVietHung, you are absolutely totally wrong. The one hundred percent correct way to check that an object is the null object is to compare "object == [NSNull null]". Please read the documentation of the NSNull class. There is only _one_ null object.

Comment: To the code: There is no need to check for the mutable classes. isKindOfClass checks for the class itself and all subclasses. And it is very dubious to check whether the string length or the array count is greater than zero. This makes it impossible to receive empty strings or arrays without elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can check by use of `[myDisctionary allKeys];`

Ex:

```
NSDictionary *current_instore_announcement=[result objectForKey:@"current_instore_anncouncement"];

// get the keys
NSArray *keys = [current_instore_announcement allKeys];

if([keys count]>0){
    // do something with the dictionary.
}else
    // Null Values
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *current_instore_announcement=[result objectForKey:@"current_instore_anncouncement"];
if ([current_instore_announcement isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    //nil or null will not be here, and just do NSDictionary parsing here
}
```

or else:

```
if (![current_instore_announcement isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
    //not null class will be here, NSDictionary, nil, empty string will all be parsed here
}
```